# How do I retrieve text from a span tag inside a selected href tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve the text from a span elementinside a selected href tag.  Here is my HTML from a previous example:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb1.jpg' alt="">
        <span class="gifttitle">Thumb1</span>
    </a>    
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb2.jpg' alt="">
        <span class="gifttitle">Thumb2</span>
    </a>    
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img class="giftthumb" src='thumb3.jpg' alt="">
        <span class="gifttitle">Thumb3</span>
    </a>    
</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Test" id="capture"/>
```

My jQuery looks like this

```
$('#capture').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var test = $(".highlight .gifttitle").text();       
    alert("TEXT " + test);
});
```

Once an item is selected I add a class called: 'highlight'

Comment: how the href would be selected? will there be a css class name 'selected' applied to it? `:selected` pseudo selector works for option elements

Comment: `selected href tag`. What does it mean?

Comment: @3nigma ... _actually for option elements_.

Comment: There is a class applied to the selected item called: 'highlight'

Comment: @undefined thanks for the correction i mixed it up with the :checked ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just a need a simple class selector:

```
var test = $(".gifttitle.highlight").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shold change your code to:

```
$('#capture').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // var test = $(".gifttitle", this).text();      
    alert("TEXT " + test);
});
```

The `:selected` pseudoclass is not applied to `span` elements.

The `$(". gifttitle ", this)` means select the element with class `gifttitle` in current element.

Answer (score 0):

var test = $('.highlight > .gifttitle').text();